# Squares in the Squares

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

Given input of a positive integer `n`, write a program that completes the following process.

- Find the smallest positive integer greater than `n` that is a perfect square and is the concatenation of `n` and some other number. The order of the digits of `n` may not be changed. The number concatenated onto `n` to produce a perfect square may be called `r_1`.
- If `r_1` is not a perfect square, repeat the above process with `r_1` as the new input to the process. Repeat until `r_k` is a perfect square, denoted `s`.
- Print the value of `sqrt(s)`.

Input can be taken in any format. You can assume that `n` is a positive integer. If any `r_k` has a leading zero (and `r_k`≠0), the zero can be ignored.

---

**Test cases**

Here are some test cases. The process demonstrates the above steps.

```
Input:   23
Process: 23, 2304, 4
Output:  2

Input:   10
Process: 10, 100, 0
Output:  0

Input:   1
Process: 1, 16, 6, 64, 4
Output:  2

Input:   5
Process: 5, 529, 29, 2916, 16
Output:  4

Input:   145
Process: 145, 145161, 161, 16129, 29, 2916, 16
Output:  4

Input:   1337
Process: 1337, 13373649, 3649, 36493681, 3681, 368102596, 2596, 25969216, 9216
Output:  96
```

---

This is code golf. Standard rules apply. The shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 35 <s>44.0</s> bytes

```
XK``x@2^tVKVXf1=a~]VKVnQ0h)UXKX^t1\
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WEtgYHhAMl50VktWWGYxPWF-XVZLVm5RMGgpVVhLWF50MVw&input=MjM)

```
XK        % implicit input: n. Copy to clipboard K
`         % do...while. Each iteration applies the algorithm
  `       %   do...while. Each iteration tests a candidate number
    x     %     delete top of stack
    @2^   %     iteration index squared
    t     %     duplicate
    V     %     convert to string                
    K     %     paste from clipboard K: n or r_k
    V     %     convert to string  
    Xf    %     find one string within another. Gives indices of starting matches, if any 
    1=a~  %     test if some of those indices is 1. If not: next iteration
  ]       %   end. We finish with a perfect square that begins with digits of n or r_k
  V       %   convert to string
  K       %   paste from clipboard K: n or r_k
  VnQ0h   %   index of rightmost characters, as determined by r_k
  )       %   keep those figures only
  U       %   convert to number. This is the new r_k
  XK      %   copy to clipboard K, to be used as input to algorithm again, if needed
  X^      %   square root
  1\      %   fractional part. If not zero: apply algorithm again
          % implitic do...while loop end
          % implicit display
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
LsI@b2 fy=sh.fys+QZ1\0)@Q2
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=LsI%40b2+fy%3Dsh.fys%2BQZ1%5C0%29s%40Q2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=23%0A10%0A1%0A5%0A145%0A1337&debug=0)

Output is as a float. If output as an int is desired, it would be 1 extra byte.

Explanation:

```
LsI@b2 fy=sh.fys+QZ1\0)s@Q2
                               Q = eval(input())
L                              def y(b): return
   @b2                         Square root of b
 sI                            Is an integer.
       f              )        Find the first positive integer T that satisfies
           h.f     1\0         Find the first digit string Z that satisfies
                +QZ            Concatenation of Q and Z
               s               Converted to an integer
              y                Is a pergect square.
          s                    Convert the string to an integer
         =                     Assign result to the next variable in the code, Q
        y                      Repeat until result is a perfect square
                               (The space) Discard return value
                        @Q2    Take square root of Q and print.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 98

```py
i=input();d=o=9
while~-d:
 n=i;d=o+1;o=i=0
 while(n*d+i)**.5%1:i=-~i%d;d+=9*d*0**i
print'%d'%n**.5
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/yBmkTd).

Comment: Since we're in float abuse territory anyway... `while x**.5%1:` maybe?

Comment: @Sp3000 thanks! I've golfed it down a bit more now.

Comment: @Ampora only the ideone link printed the process, but I've changed that now.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>200</strike> <strike>198</strike> 178 bytes

```
import math
def r(i):
 j=int(i**.5)+1
 while str(j*j)[:len(str(i))]!=str(i):j+=1
 return int(str(j*j)[len(str(i)):])
q=r(int(input()))
while math.sqrt(q)%1!=0:q=r(q)
print(q**.5)
```

Comment: You could save a good number of bytes by shortening `math.sqrt` to `m`.

Comment: @Ampora Aww yeah, saved 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 26 bytes

```
{~a₀X√ℕ∧YcX∧Yh?∧Ybcℕ≜!}ⁱ√ℕ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv7ou8VFTQ8SjjlmPWqY@6lgemRwBIjPsQWRSMkiwc45i7aPGjRAl//9HGxnrGBroGOqY6hiamMYCAA)

The last test case was omitted in the TIO link because it alone takes more than a minute to execute. I ran it on my laptop and the correct result was achieved in no more than two hours.

```
{                             The input
 ~a₀                          is a prefix of
    X√                        X, the square root of which
      ℕ                       is a whole number.
       ∧YcX                   Y concatenated is X.
           ∧Yh?               The input is the first element of Y.
               ∧Yb            The rest of Y,
                  c           concatenated,
                      }       is the output
                   ℕ          which is a whole number.
                    ≜         Make sure that it actually has a value,
                     !        and discard all choice points.
{                     }ⁱ      Keep feeding that predicate its own output until
                        √     its output's square root
                         ℕ    is a whole number
                              which is the output.
```

The second-to-last `ℕ` is necessary for when the initial input is already a perfect square, so the first perfect square which has it as a prefix is itself, and `!` is necessary to make sure that backtracking iterates instead of finding a larger concatenated square, but I don't really know why `≜` is necessary, I just know that 5 produces a wrong answer without it.

Comment: (Thanks to a bug in the parser, that horrible mess of named variables and `∧`s is actually shorter than using a sandwich.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 101 bytes

```perl6
my&q={$^k;$_=({++($||=$k.sqrt.Int)**2}.../^$k/)[*-1];+S/$k//}
put (q(get),&q...!(*.sqrt%1))[*-1].sqrt
```

```perl6
my &q = {
  $^k; # declare placeholder parameter
  # set default scalar to:
  $_ = ( # a list
    # code block that generates every perfect square
    # larger than the input
    { ++( $ ||= $k.sqrt.Int )**2 }
    ...   # produce a sequence
    /^$k/ # ending when it finds one starting with the argument
  )[*-1]; # last value in sequence

  # take the last value and remove the argument
  # and turn it into a number to remove leading zeros
  +S/$k//
}

put (     # print the result of:
  q(get),     # find the first candidate
  &q          # find the rest of them
  ...         # produce a sequence
  !(*.sqrt%1) # ending with a perfect square
)[*-1]        # last value in sequence
.sqrt         # find the sqrt
```

Answer (score 0):

### ES7, 116 bytes

```
n=>{do{for(i=n;!(r=(''+Math.ceil((i*=10)**0.5)**2)).startsWith(+n););n=r.replace(+n,'');r=n**0.5}while(r%1);return r}
```

Yes, I could probably save a byte by using `eval`.